# search in sql with 2 input parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i have 2 input parameter and i want search with These

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl_answer
 (
  an_del INT,
  u_username NVARCHAR(50),
  u_name NVARCHAR(50) null
  )

INSERT dbo.tbl_answer
VALUES(1, 'mohammad', null), (1, 'A13A6C533AF77160FBF2862953FA4530', 'GCV'), (1, 'C', 'GG'), (0, 'AB', 'BB'), (1, 'AC', 'K')
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.SearchAnswers
@Username nvarchar(20),
@Name nvarchar(20)
AS
SELECT *  
FROM dbo.tbl_answer
WHERE an_del = 1 AND u_username LIKE ISNULL('%' + @Username + '%', u_username)
  and u_name LIKE  ISNULL('%' + @Name + '%', u_name)
```

and i run this command `EXEC dbo.SearchAnswers 'moha', null` but return any data
[look at this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95d2a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
CREATE PROC dbo.Answers
@Username nvarchar(20),
@Name nvarchar(20)
AS

declare  @Name2 nvarchar(20)
set @Name2 = ISNULL(@Name, '00')

SELECT *  
FROM dbo.tbl_answer
WHERE an_del = 1 AND ( u_username LIKE ISNULL('%' + @Username + '%', u_username)
  AND  
ISNULL(u_name,'00') LIKE  '%' + @Name2 + '%' )
```

Comment: if you are satisfy with my ans then upvot me

Answer (score 0):

Here you are searching for 2 fields `username` and `name` and input parameter is `null`. 
`Like` will not work for `null` so you have to check for null independently or put some supplementary for that...

```
CREATE PROC dbo.SearchAnswers
@Username nvarchar(20),
@Name nvarchar(20)
AS

declare  @Name2 nvarchar(20)
set @Name2 = ISNULL(@Name, '00')

SELECT *  
FROM dbo.tbl_answer
WHERE an_del = 1 AND ( u_username LIKE ISNULL('%' + @Username + '%', u_username)
  AND  
ISNULL(u_name,'00') LIKE  '%' + @Name2 + '%' )
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00a65/9)

Comment: Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question? This would be very helpful to the person asking the question, and anyone else who comes along.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you aren't allowing for `u_name` to be null in your table.  Which it is, on the only record with a `u_username` containing "moha"

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SearchAnswers
@Username nvarchar(20),
@Name nvarchar(20)
AS
SELECT *  
FROM dbo.tbl_answer
WHERE an_del = 1 
AND u_username LIKE ISNULL('%' + @Username + '%', u_username)
AND ISNULL(u_name,'') LIKE  ISNULL('%' + @Name + '%', u_name)
```

You could also have the third conditional explicity test for NULL.

```
AND ( (u_name is null) or (u_name LIKE ISNULL('%' + @Name + '%', u_name) )
```